# Cannot record 1080p video with most apps

Tags: settings, camera

I have rooted ZTE v987 and according to specification it has ability to record 1080p@30fps video. The problem is - I can't do this with most apps. I changed my ROM multiple times and every time I have the same problem.
I usually use app called [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) and I can record full HD video, but this wanted to use other app (for timelapses) and it also detects only low resolution (640x480).

How can I force all apps on the phome to use maximum resolution? Maybe is there some fault of config? Or maybe hardware fault? But as I said, some apps detect 1080p as available resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Open Camera app uses [Camera API2](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/versioning.html) which allows apps to fully utilize the camera hardware and opens up even more features (if your hardware supports) to apps. Unless the app in question (the one you use to make time-lapse) has been  implemented using CameraAPI2 you may not get the full features you state you get from Open Camera.

Alternatively some [apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.vipek.camera2&hl=en) may have implemented API2 but may require some payment to unlock the "pro" features which can include full HD video recording or RAW image capture.